# Percentage Problem: How to calculate how much % each "x" per 100,000 accounts for?

Tags: statistics, percentages

Per the [study](https://www.pnas.org/content/early/2019/07/30/1821204116) using data from the [National Vital Statistic System](https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/nvss/index.htm) for men between the ages of 26-29 years:

1. Accidents: 76.6 deaths per 100,000
2. Suicide: 26.7 deaths per 100,000
3. Homicides (Not Involving Police): 22.0 deaths per 100,000
4. Heart Disease: 7.0 deaths per 100,000
5. Cancer: 6.3 deaths per 100,000

How would I calculate how much percentage each of these causes accounts for?

Example: Accidents account for 70% of deaths, and Cancer accounts for 6% of death and something like that

Comment: From this list alone, you do not. You would need an exhaustive list of all death causes for that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But If you were to assume that these 5 are the only causes of death, then it should still be possible to work it out?

Comment: It is, yes. As a hint to work out the formula: Maybe consider simpler examples (just two death causes, nice numbers, …) first and then try to generalize.